# Is SOAP a stateful protocol? Is REST really stateless? How can one store data using REST?

Tags: rest, soap, protocols, stateless, stateful

Is SOAP designed to be a stateful? How can it be reached? SOAP use RPC, so where to store data?

Is REST designed to be a stateless? Is it possible to store data in JSON ? Is it so wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. You should avoid asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: Although these are interesting questions, StackOverflow is meant more for solving specific programming problems than it is for discussing broader conceptual ideas. You might find a better audience for these kinds of questions at Software Engineering https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Additionally, try to keep it to one question per "ask". It really helps keep the answers focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is REST designed to be a stateless?

Yes, it really is -- but Fielding is precise about what [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) means in the context of REST:

> communication must be stateless in nature, as in the client-stateless-server (CSS) style of Section 3.4.3 (Figure 5-3), such that each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

In other words, to correctly interpret a request, the server does not need to *remember* any previous requests.

For example, contrast HTTP (where credentials are part of the metadata of the request) with FTP (where credentials are sent separately from the RETR command).

Comment: so, how to keep state? (suppose i use spring (boot) techstack)

Comment: @arminvanbuuren `*communication* must be stateless.` This does not mean the the service cannot store state. Most commonly you would store [state in a database](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/state_repository), but there are also valid situations where you can [store state in the messages to and from the client](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/state_messaging)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing SOAP with REST is not so suitable, because SOAP is a protocol based on XML and REST is an architectural style that is by definition not bringged to a specific technology.

In any case the common use of REST is via http, like SOAP, and the common usage of REST with json and http is only a comfortable implementation that is very suitable for web development and machine to machine communication due to the incredible good support for json in almost all the modern programming language.

Said that SOAP is definitely stateless!.
When we fire a web service call with soap we create a SOAP envelop in xml and send it on a http channel, that is stateless by default.

During the years near to SOAP many other protocols that can be used with SOAP can add some feature to the protocol the well known WS-*. BPEL deserves some discussion, it is the most important standard for SOAP orchestration.
Even if with BPEL in my experience the engine provide a SOAP web service in order to create a "state full" web service, the fact that a BPEL process is exposed via SOAP it is not correlated with SOAP. BPEL is BPEL and SOAP is SOAP are two separated things.

said that yes REST is an architectural style that is stateless by design and it is particular suitable and used with http, but even soap is a stateless protocol that use http like transportation layer.

for the storing data part of the question, storing data is a application concern. Of course you can pass data in a rest api like a SOAP web service. For the SOAP web service usually you will post data on the body of the SOAP envelop. In a REST service typically you are creating/updating a resource and for this reason using the classical http implementation of REST you will perform a POST(create)/PUT(update all the resource)/
PATCH(update only a piece of resource) pasing the data in the body of the http request. of course do not forget the Content-Type http header on application/json.

I hope that it can help you